# Is there any parsers to convert SQL to tree (AST)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have SQL expression for Postgres. And i want to get [`Abstract syntax tree`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) to manipulate this from Java program.
I have found `sqlite-parser` (find it google, please, I have not enough reputation) from `code-school` but it`s in develop.

So, do you know another parsers that could execute from Java program ? If it is possible, write almost stable parsers, please.

Comment: Have you considered using [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API)? Is has the "Criteria API" which allows (among other things) dynamic modification of database queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/lfittl/pg_query This library using native functions from Postgres engine to build tree from SQL